# PHP User Account System

Tags: php

Am new to php and trying my hands on a php login system from [this](http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/3280-how-to-make-a-user-account-system/) page But am bit confuse about a piece of code.

Code snippet presented below.

```html
<?php

class UserPermissions {

 const READ_POSTS = 1;
 const POST_NEW_THREADS = 2;
 const POST_NEW_REPLIES = 4;
 const EDIT_OWN_POSTS = 8;
 const EDIT_OTHERS_POSTS = 16;
 const DELETE_OWN_POSTS = 32;
 const DELETE_OTHERS_POSTS = 64;
 const MOVE_THREADS = 128;
 const SPLIT_THREADS = 256;
 const MERGE_THREADS = 512;
 const BAN_USERS = 1024;
 const WARN_USERS = 2048;
 const ACCESS_ADMIN_PANEL = 4096;
 // And so on and so on
 
 protected $perms;
 
 function __construct($permissions) {
  $this->perms = $permissions;
 }
 
 function hasPermission($perm) {
  return ($this->perms & $perm) === $perm;
 }
}

?>
```

The main focus is the hasPermision function and how the return value is calculated.

Comment: It's a bit-wise comparison. Read up on the bit-wise and operator (`&`).

Answer (score 0):

PHP.net will be your best friend. Here's their explanation to your question about comparators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Basically, $perm must be equal but also of the same type.

Here's the link to the bitwise doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php